# ImmutableJs : Updating a List in nested Map

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have a hard reading the ImmutableJS and other questions answers... It seems simple, I have a Map like this :

```
{
  foo: [
    {id: 1, name: 'John'}, 
    {id: 2, name: 'Christine'}, 
    {id: 3, name: 'Frank'}, 
    {id: 4, name: 'Jenny'},
  ]
}
```

How can i update change "John" to "Johnny" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/setIn) you can use this:

```
newMap = oldMap.setIn(['foo', 0, 'name'], 'Johnny');
```

You pass an array of keys, then the value.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer. Sorry if I was not clear enough, actually I'd like to only update the Map with the `id` = 1 to "Johnny", how can I do that ?

Comment: You have to get the index first by looping through the arrays inside `foo` then use `setIn(['foo', index, 'name', 'value')`